# Quality issues with tan-colored Lego pieces?

Tags: colour, quality

I recently bought an expensive Lego set with a large number of tan-colored pieces. I was very disappointed to find out that *more than a dozen* (isn't that a spectacularly large number?) of 1x1 bricks had significant cracks (see picture). As I've only had problems with tan pieces, this seems to me like a systematic quality problem.

[image]

The tan pieces generally feel weaker than other colors, and it seems probable even more cracks will emerge later.

Question: Is it true that Lego has systematic issues with tan-colored pieces?

Answer (score 11):

Please contact LEGO customer service. They will send you new pieces, and even more importantly, they will make note about the quality issues. The following quote is from the LEGO Ambassador forum in regards to quality issues by Keith Severson, who is the senior manager for community support at LEGO. It is about recent quality problems with another LEGO element (32x32 baseplates), but the same steps apply in your case:

> "The only way quality and engineering review potential issues is through data that is gathered through customer service. Every time a customer (such as yourself) call in it is logged with the specific element. Once that element receives a certain about of issues they will review it. So the best thing you can do is have your LUG members to report this through the system."

In the USA you can call LEGO Customer Service at 1-800-835-4386 8am - 10pm (EST) Monday - Friday and 10am to 6pm (EST) on Saturday and Sunday. If you are in another country, you can check the official LEGO website for phone number and hours of operation.

Comment: Thanks. I filed a complaint through [Bricks and Pieces website](https://service.lego.com/en-gb/replacementparts#BasicInfo) and hope to receive new parts within 10 days. [This blog post](http://gimmelego.blogspot.se/2011/03/bigand-finished.html) discusses quality problems with tan pieces.

Comment: I have received the replacement parts now, no questions asked. The accompanying letter apologized and told me not to hesitate contacting Lego again should any new problems arise.

Comment: Awesome! Yes, LEGO's customer service is excellent. :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the quality issues, but my experience has been that you can just call LEGO customer service, tell them the issue and the amount of affected pieces, and they will send you free replacements.